# How to get active UDP hosts accesssed within an application - windows?

Tags: c#, windows, networking, tcp, udp

I am planning on trying to put into my application c# - an active overlay while playing in-game , the active IP host for **UDP** connections such that u can track which server u are connected to.

I have managed to do this using netstat for **TCP Connections** - however am failing to get accurate **UDP connection** hosts.
There is an application like **livetcpudp** watch i have seen that does something similar by using windows event / kernel logs or something like that.

from my research **UDP** is connectionless - how can I capture this info?